# How to insert a new row using JS HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

*However, the problem is upon clicking again the add button, columns are being created on the same row instead of a new row is created. Can somebody help me regarding to my problem?*

```js
var id = 0;
 tblStudent = document.getElementById("tblStudent");

 function insertValue() {
  id++;
  var txtFirstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
  var txtLastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value;
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  var tdValue = document.createTextNode(id);
  if(id != "") {
   td.appendChild(tdValue);
   tblStudent.insertBefore(td, tblStudent.lastChild);

  
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  var tdValue = document.createTextNode(txtFirstName);
  if(txtFirstName != "") {
   td.appendChild(tdValue);
   tblStudent.insertBefore(td, tblStudent.lastChild);
  
  
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  var tdValue = document.createTextNode(txtLastName);
  if(txtLastName != "") {
   td.appendChild(tdValue);
   tblStudent.insertBefore(td, tblStudent.lastChild);
   }
  }
 } 
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName"><br><br>
 <input type="text" id="txtLastName"><br><br>
 <button onclick= "insertValue()">Add</button>
 <table border = "1px">
  <th>ID</th> 
  <th>FirstName</th>
  <th>LastName</th> 
  <tbody id = "tblStudent">
   
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: If you need a new row you will have to create it. Then you can add columns.

Comment: You are missing `<tr>` elements. Both in your markup and the JS code.

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-cookbook/9781449390211/ch12s13.html

Comment: I don't need to create a new column name. I just need to insert a new row by clicking the ADD button. How can I do so?